# Domain group hierarchical group membership and SQL Logins mapped to AD groups

Tags: security, windows, authentication

SQL Version: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.4035.00 (X64) 
    Nov 24 2008 16:17:31 
    Copyright (c) 1988-2005 Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 (Build 7601: Service Pack 1)

This is the AD group structure:

- Group A

  - User 4
  - Group B

    - User 1
    - User 2
    - User 3

I granted Group A login access to my SQL instance (connect and dataReader/writer to Northwind db).

I'd expect to be able to login to sql with User 1-4 but in fact only User 4 is allowed to login. If i grant Group B access then all users can login as expected.

So I'd venture to answer my own question and say "NO - sql only respects the 1st-level members of an AD sec group" but I wanted confirmation from someone else.

Logs show state 11 login failure which indicates "Valid login but server access failure."

Comment: Was Group B made a member of Group A very recently? The users may have to log off and log on again. See my answer [here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/35424/how-to-refresh-ad-security-group-on-sql-server-permissions/35466#35466).

Comment: Thanks for responding.. I read the other posting and I've read other ones like it. I've had User1 log off his machine and log back on and still no luck. Group A and group B were both created/updated like 3 days ago and its very likely users haven't logged off since.. I will have User2 again after logging off first to make sure.

Comment: Should xp_logininfo show the members listed within sub-groups? 

EXEC xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\GROUP_A','members'

Comment: confirmed that User2 is not able to login either AFTER clean logoff-logon... any thoughts ? error "Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 11."

Comment: I've never used `xp_logininfo` before -- try it and see what happens. Is either Group A or Group B the `BUILTIN\Administrators` group by any chance?

Comment: Oh, by the way, I recreated the scenario you presented, and I was able to log in successfully as User 1/2/3 (as I expected), so there's something else going on here.

Comment: Interesting..  no, nor Group A nor B are in BUILTIN\Admins...

Comment: Can you set up a test of the security on some other object (e.g., permissions on a file in a network share) to see if it works correctly there? I want to see if this is a SQL Server issue, or something else is going on with AD.

Comment: Hey Jon - thanks for your help.. the fact that you tried to repro really helped in answering this question but I think i don't have vote-Up reputation points yet.. anyways, nothing's changed since last night but I tried it this morning and now it's working.. even xp_logininfo returns the appropiate listing of memberships for User1-3.. very weird but i did read someone else post about a lag for working with windows auth logins.

Answer (score 1):

This answer may not be of any real value since now the question becomes WHY is there a lag...

but the AD changes were done 3 days ago and in my particular case, it took 3 days before SQL Server started recognizing the new members/groups added.

As of last night, when i executed EXEC xp_logininfo 'DOMAIN\User1','all' it returned nothing.. today (4th day since change) it shows the permission path as 'DOMAIN\GroupA'.

Comment: Slow AD replication? That's the only thing I can think of.