# SQL Server AD groups membership seems cached - how to flush to test?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, active-directory

I am configuring a new, fully AD group based security scheme on an existing SQL Server 2008.

When I change the group to which I belong to test my configs, it seems that there is quite a delay between the change and it appearing in SQL Server.

To try and improve this I do:

```
repadmin /syncall /Ade (to force full domain syncing)
DBCC FREESYSTEMCACHE(‘TokenAndPermUserStore’)
```

I've also tried disconnecting and reconnecting the user in SSMS.

Any idea how I can get the AD group permissions to apply faster? Testing once every ten minutes is painful!

Answer (score 1):

AG Groups are only updated when the user gets a new token from the domain controller.  The only way to speed this process up that I know of is to log off the machine and log back in.

I would recommend using a Virtual Machine to do this so that you don't want to kill yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`klist purge`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh134826%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

> Allows you to delete a specific ticket. Purging tickets will destroy all tickets that you have cached, so use this attribute with caution. It might stop you from being able to authenticate to resources. If this happens, you will have to log off and log on again.