# Change login name for all objects on server

Tags: sql-server, active-directory

Example,

I have a create a windows login `DOMAIN\GROUP01`, and mapped that login to a database `DATABASE01` with lets say `DB_OWNER` permissions

I want to change the login name, I went into Active Directory, changed the name to `DOMAIN\GROUP01_OLD`, and ran the following query in SQL, on the `master` db :

```
alter login [DOMAIN\GROUP01] with name = [DOMAIN\GROUP01_OLD]
```

So far so good, the login is renamed. 
Now comes the actual problem. When I look into the `security->users` settings of `DATABASE01`, the login still has the old value; `DOMAIN\GROUP01`

How can I change this at one level, instead of doing it at multiple databases?

Reason I am asking this, i need to rename +/- 500 groups, I am doing this with scripts. This will take a hell of time if I need to change it manually for all databases at `DOMAIN\GROUP01` level

PS: I am a SQL newbie, so please bear with me.

Comment: If you want the names to match then you are going to have to rename them at all levels.  However, you say you are using scripts so it shouldn't be that much of an effort.  Create a script that will take old name and new name and have it walk the databases issuing the rename command.  Have that script read from a text file.  You could even have the script do the AD renaming if you wanted.

Comment: Well I actually have a script that renames the AD groups, but for some reason they dont seem to replicate the new names into SQL. Is this normal behavior, or am I missing something crucial?

Comment: That's normal behavior.  SQL uses the Security Identifier to tie the objects together, the name isn't terribly important.  It will get confusing later, though.

Comment: That's  a shame, would have made my day a lot easier if it would replicate. ;). I'll try to build some kind of script to rename the groups at all levels.

Comment: It's possible you just need to restart SQL Server to force it to pull from AD again. Some of this may just be caching.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thanks for the input, is there a way to force this after a reboot, I tried rebooting, but for some reason the name stays the old value

Comment: Might requite more than that - [this seemed to work for another user](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/41101/1186).

Comment: @AaronBertrand, I use a local workstation with a SQL install for testing purposes, so when I reboot the machine, I also logoff. Unfortunately it made no difference for replicating the names in SQL.